# The outcome is always odd instead of even or odd

Tags: python

The outcome is always odd, instead of even or odd.

```
num = input("write a number: ")

thenum = int(num)/2
if thenum != int:
  print("Your number is odd")
elif thenum == int:
  print("Your number is even)
```

Comment: `thenum != int` is not the way to test if a number is an integer.

Comment: What you want is `if type(thenum) is int:`

Comment: But it's simpler to do `if num % 2 == 1:`

Comment: @Barmar, this won't work here because e.g. `type(6/3)` is `float`

Comment: Why do I feel like I’ve seen this already today? @Barmar does this look familiar to you? In any case, I’m voting to close this since it’s trivial and unlikely to ever be useful to anyone else.

Comment: @AMC I feel like I've seen it before, but not recently. I couldn't find a dup, although it seems like it should be common.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe it’s been deleted? I could have sworn it was this exact user, although I may just have developed the ability to see the future/parallel universes.

Comment: @AMC https://stackoverflow.com/q/59653453/1672429

Comment: @StefanPochmann Thanks! I think that’s reason enough to close this question, even though it can’t technically be flagged as a duplicate. Wow, and that first one looks like a copy/pasted assignment, too. It seems OP got enough comments to solve this on the previous question, but didn’t even try to do anything themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You want `thenum` to be the modulus, so change to `int(num)%2`. If the number is even, there will be no remainder, so `thenum` will be equal to 0. So your `if` statement should be:

```
if thenum == 0:
    print("Your number is even")
else:
    print("Your number is odd")
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to test if a number is even or odd by dividing by 2 and checking if the result is an `int` or a `float`.

However, that doesn't work, since `/` is an operator that always returns a `float`, even if the result could have been an `int`. For example:

```
>>> 4/2
2.0
>>> type(4/2)
<class 'float'>
```

You could turn the result into an `int` and see if the results are equal if you really wanted to use this method:

```
>>> 5/2 == int(5/2)
False
>>> 4/2 == int(4/2)
True
```

But that's really relying on a side effect of the type conversion and not very good programming.

Better would be to actually check if the division by two has a remainder, so:

```
>>> 5%2
1
>>> 4%2
0
```

So, your code would be:

```
num = input("write a number: ")

remainder = num % 2
if remainder == 1:
    print("Your number is odd")
else:
    print("Your number is even")
```

Note that the `elif` isn't needed either, since there's only two possible outcomes for the remainder when dividing an `int` by 2.

Answer (score 0):

Your way but done properly with `thenum.is_integer()` instead of your `thenum == int` attempt (which is as flawed as asking "Is *my cat* the *species* of all cats?"):

```
num = input("write a number: ")

thenum = int(num)/2
if not thenum.is_integer():
  print("Your number is odd")
elif thenum.is_integer():
  print("Your number is even")
```

Though it would be nicer with a few changes:

```
number = input("write a number: ")

half = int(number) / 2
if half.is_integer():
    print("Your number is even")
else:
    print("Your number is odd")
```